# If $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. random variables, is $P(X < Y) = P(Y < X)$?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I am trying to solve the following probability problem:

> If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) random variables, is $P(X < Y) = P(Y < X)$?

Source: https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/files/stat110/files/strategic_practice_and_homework_5.pdf (Pg 2, Qn 2)

The answer provided on Pg 7 (of the pdf) states:

> If $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d., then $P(X < Y) = P(Y < X)$ by symmetry: we can
>   interchange $X$ and $Y$ since both are the probability of one draw from the
>   distribution being less than another, independent draw.

However, my intuition tells me that since $X$ and $Y$ could be entirely different functions, the above explanation seems a little "handwavy" (e.g. $Y$ could take on values that are very much larger than $X$). So I guess I need a little algebraic proof to convince myself but I am unable to do so on my own.

Could anyone please advise me on how to prove why this statement is true/false via an **algebraic** proof?

Comment: "could be entirely different functions" -- what do you mean by this? By assumption $X, Y$ are not just independent but also *identically distributed*.

Comment: @MeesdeVries I mean different functions could have the same distribution right? So $X$ and $Y$ could be different.

Comment: You mean as functions $\Omega \to \mathbb R$? That makes sense -- in fact by independence they have to be different (except in degenerate cases).

Comment: @MeesdeVries Yes. Exactly. That's what is confusing me because I am thinking something like "what if $Y$ often take on much larger values than $X$. Then $X$ would be more likely to be smaller than $Y$"?  Do you get what I mean?

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. In this case your intuition is leading you astray: the precise functional form of a random variable is usually not that relevant, and the situation you worry is ruled out precisely by "identically distributed". But a thorough algebraic proof may be useful to you to steel your intuition.

Comment: The annoying part of a formal proof is writing the set $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x > y\}$ as a countable union of disjoint 'half-open' rectangles such that if $[a, b) \times [c, d)$ is a rectangle in the set, then so is $[c, d) \times [a, b)$. This is entirely doable, just tedious. If you are willing to accept that this collection of rectangles exists, the proof is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Wow same profile photo! Also, the switch of x and y in the title is like a converse statement which is not always true to the original. This is simply one observation, please do not ask me elaborate.

Answer (score 3):

$P(X<Y)=P(Y-X>0) =P(X-Y >0)=P(X>Y)$ where the second equality follows from the fact that the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ is same as the joint distribution of $(Y,X)$.

To add more details let $E=\{(x,y): y>x\}$. Then $P(Y-X >0)=P((X,Y) \in E)=P((Y,X) \in E)=P(X-Y)>0$.

To prove that $(X,Y)$ and $(Y,X)$ have the same distribution note that $P((X,Y) \in A \times B)=P(X\in A)P(Y \in B)=P(X\in B)P(Y \in A)=P((Y,X) \in A \times B).$ In the first step I used independence and in the second step I used the fact that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution.

If $\mu$ and $\nu$ are measures on the Borel sets of $\mathbb  R^{2}$ such that $\mu (A \times B)=\nu (A \times B)$ for all Borel sets $A$ and $B$ in $\mathbb  R$ the $\mu=\nu$. This follows from standard arguments in measure theory: the class of finite disjoint unions of measurable rectangles forms a field which generates the Borel sigma field on $\mathbb  R^{2}$. Hence $(X,Y)$ and $(Y,X)$ have the same distribution.

Comment: I don't think this quite meets the standard OP is looking for. It reduces the problem to proving that $(X, Y)$ and $(Y, X)$ have the same joint distribution, but this is not immediate from just the fact that they are independent and identically distributed (except by the same symmetry argument that OP wants to avoid).

Comment: @MeesdeVries I have added a proof. I hope this is accessible to OP but I am not sure.

Comment: This proves it for rectangles in the plane, which is of course the important part; but now you still need to prove that it holds for your $E$, which is the unimportant but more difficult part.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P_X$ and $P_Y$ denote the pushforward of $P$ by $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Since $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution, $P_X$ and $P_Y$ are equal to some common $Q$: $P_X=P_Y=Q$. Now, note that

$$\begin{align}
P(X<Y) &= \int_{\mathbb R^2} 1_{x<y} dP_{(X,Y)}(x,y) \tag{1} \\
&= \int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R} 1_{x<y} dP_{X}(x) dP_{Y}(y) \tag{2}\\
&= \int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R} 1_{x<y} dQ(x) dQ(y) \\
&= \int_{\mathbb R^2} 1_{y<x} dQ(y) dQ(x) \tag{3}\\
&= P(Y<X)
\end{align}$$

$\text{(1)}$: Law of the unconscious statistician
$\text{(2)}$: Independence of $X$ and $Y$
$\text{(3)}$: Renaming the variables of integration

Here is an additional way. Note the equalities between measures

$$\begin{align}
P_{(X,Y)} &= P_X\otimes P_Y \tag 1 \\
&= P_Y\otimes P_X \tag 2 \\
&= P_{(Y,X)}
\end{align}$$

$\text{(1)}$: Independence of $X$ and $Y$
$\text{(2)}$: $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution, thus $P_X=P_Y$ and $P_Y=P_X$

Consequently, $(X,Y)\stackrel{(d)}=(Y,X)$. Letting $f:(x,y)\mapsto 1_{x<y}$, composing with this measurable function preserves equality in distribution, so that $f(X,Y)\stackrel{(d)}=f(Y,X)$ and taking expectations
$$E[f(X,Y)]=E[f(Y,X)] \iff P(X<Y) = P(Y<X).$$

Comment: Can you explain why we use pushforwad and not just the joint density? Also, could you please explain step (3) more in-depth? In this last step, it seems that we are setting x and y equal to each other, which would be strange.

Comment: @Adel $X$ (and thus $(X,Y)$) may fail to have a density (w.r.t. to Lebesgue measure or a counting measure). To preserve generality I use pushforward measures. In the integral $\int\int 1_{x<y} dQ(x) dQ(y)$, the variables $x$ and $y$ are **dummy variables** that only serve for integrating. You can replace the letter $x$ with the letter $s$ and $y$ with $t$ to get the same integral $\int\int 1_{s<t} dQ(s) dQ(t)$. Now replace $s$ with $y$ and $t$ with $x$ to get  $\int\int 1_{y<x} dQ(y) dQ(x)$, as advertised.

Comment: Also, I've added another proof.

Comment: thanks for this. I prefer the solution with integration, as I understand that better. So if we assume that $X$ and $Y$ do have densities, then if understand you correctly, we can just work with the (joint) density instead of the pushforward. The proof would look like, $P(X<Y) =\int_{XY}I(x<y)v(x,y)dxdy=\int_Y\int_X I(x<y)f(x)f(y)dxdy=\int_X\int_YI(y<x)f(y)f(x)dydx$, where $v()$ is the joint density, while $f()$ is the marginal distribution. The marginal is the same for both $X$ and $Y$ by assumption. In the second equality we use iid and the last we use change of variables.

Comment: @Adel Yes, I think you've understood correctly. However, what do you mean by integrating on the domains $XY$, $Y$ and $X$ (e.g. $\int_{XY}$, $\int_X$) ?

Comment: In you original solution, equation (3), I am not sure I understand why we use double integration over $\mathbb{R}^2$, such as $\int_ {\mathbb{R}^2}\int$, when I think one integration, such as $\int_ {\mathbb{R}^2}$, would suffice. What am I missing?

Comment: @Adel It's a typo, now corrected, sorry !

Comment: thanks again. by "integrating over the domains" I mean integrating over the support of the random variables, $X$ and $Y$ (marginal support) and joint support $XY$.

Comment: @Adel Ok, very fine then !

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for being so responsive @Gabriel Romon.